# Why Does strlen("TRLR") cause a segfault?

Tags: c, parsing, gdb

I have a program in C that's parsing a file. It works for a small file, however, when I run it with a larger file and I reach a "TRLR" string that I try to get the length of, it causes a segfault.

```
int length = 0;
length = strlen(toParse);
```

Running this in gdb, toParse is equal to "TRLR", length is equal to 0 even after running strlen on the variable.

GDB Output:

```
Breakpoint 1, initializeField (toParse=0x7fffffffe0e2 "TRLR")
    at ./src/GEDCOMutilities.c:79
79          printf("Before length = strlen(toParse\n");
(gdb) p toParse
$12 = 0x7ffffffffffe0e2 "TRLR"
```

Edit (Code to show where the information is coming from):

```
    fgets(buffer, 255, file);
    //Check if it's a number between 0-99
    if ((isdigit(buffer[0])) || (isdigit(buffer[0] && isdigit(buffer[1])))) {
        //Get the number and store into toParse
        toParse = strtok(buffer, " ");
        int num = atoi(toParse);

        //Create and initialize a new structure with the line's other information
        StructureToStoreInto* tempStructure = initialize(toParse);
```

Essentially what I'm doing is getting a line from a file that should have a structure as such: 
Number Tag/Reference Value
So I check to make sure that the number falls between 0-99 (valid numbers), then I send the rest of the line into my initialize function to be parsed and stored into the structure. (I know regex would be a much simpler way of doing the validation)

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Due to this being for an assignment, I'm trying to avoid academic misconduct by posting code, unfortunately.

Comment: The MCVE doesn't have to be the assigment code: it can be stripped down to the minimal code that shows the problem. And one benefit of preparing the MCVE is that you discover the problem on the way. The code posted gives us nothing to go on.

Comment: Will it segfault after the next `n`?

Comment: The segfault occurs at the end of the file which is denoted by the TRLR. I've added where the toParse comes from (simplified), and a bit more info.

Comment: *The segfault occurs at the end of the file which is denoted by the TRLR* - what does it mean? You said `strlen` is causing the segfault.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and make your program compile clean (without adding any casts). Then use valgrind or gcc/clang sanitizers to catch errors.

Comment: *"The segfault occurs at the end of the file"*. What happens when `fgets` returns `NULL`, after the last line of the file (check the idiomatic way to write a loop)? It is essential to check return values from functions such as `fgets` and `strtok` which can return `NULL` before passing the pointer on.

Comment: Please remove the image of your gdb output and replace it with the output as copy-and-pasted text (formatted as code).

Comment: `strlen("TRLR")` will not cause a segfault. `strlen(toParse)` may cause a segfault if `toParse` doesn't point to a string, i.e., if `toParse` is a null pointer, or an invalid pointer, or a pointer to something that doesn't contain a terminating null character.

Comment: @KeithThompson Does it have to have a terminator at the end for strlen to work? Ex. ('\0'). I'm asking because as shown by gdb, toParse = "TRLR"

Comment: @WeatherVane In terms of fgets, I get the total number of lines in the file before executing by reading through the file character by character and adding a line any time a \n\r is found. So I don't think it could be that, but I could be mistaken?

Comment: Without MCVE this is a guessing game.

Comment: @arkdevelopment: Yes, there absolutely has to be a terminating `'\0'`. Without it, it's not a string, and `strlen` returns the length of a string. If you give it something that isn't a pointer to a string, the behavior is undefined. (If there happens to be a zero byte past the end of the object, `strlen` might return some incorrect value rather than blowing up; that's the nature of undefined behavior.)

Comment: The last line in the file may not have a newline so the count can be off by one (less). The idiomatic way to use `fgets` is `while(fgets(buffer, 255, file) != NULL) { ... }` but I would advise a bigger buffer during development to prevent a line being split.

Comment: fgets was sending in a NULL line. Problem has been fixed. Thanks guys! I don't think I can set a comment to an accepted answer, but I'd probably set Weather Vane's previous response to being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in the file may not have a newline so counting them with a first pass can be off by one (less). The idiomatic way to use `fgets` is

```
while(fgets(buffer, 255, file) != NULL) { ... }
```

but I would advise a bigger buffer during development to prevent a line being split.